# Сбыча мечт--- правильно ли во множ.числе в наст. времени

Tags: старая-орфография

Здравствуйте,сбудутся мечты,сбылись мечты-понятно. А сейчас происходит-сбыча мечт? Правильно ли так написать?

Comment: Если "сейчас происходит-сбыча мечт", тогда brigantinushka превращается в каравеллушку.

Comment: >правильно ли во множ.числе в наст. времени    
    
Ну если только "в настоящем".  )))
На грамоте как-то задали вопрос "Как склоняется счет0фактупв в настоящем времени?".

Answer (score 4):

У слова "мечта" нет формы Р.п. (фонетическое ограничение), иногда делается замена: мечтаний.
От глаголов на -БЫТЬ существительные образуются с помощью суффикса ИJ: прибыть - прибытие, но не от всех глаголов. От глагола "сбыться" существительное не образуется, поэтому также делается замена: осуществление мечтаний.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Сбыт и "сбыча" -это разные слова)

Comment: Пример  безграмотности  из  той  же  оперы.

Comment: Это просто юмористика.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант этого юмора: сбыченность мечт)